# Create Sink based on materialised value of a Source

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I want to build a Flow around a Pubsub topic

```
\-----------------------------------------------------\
 \  ------------------  ------------    -------------  \
  > > wrapWithPublish > > toPubsub |    | fromPubsub >  >
 /  ------------------  ------------    -------------  /
/-----------------------------------------------------/
```

This is the code I wrote so far

```
def mediatorFlow[In, Out](mediator: ActorRef, topic: String): Flow[In, Out, Unit] = {
  val source =
    Source
      .actorRef[Out](10, OverflowStrategy.dropHead)
      .mapMaterializedValue { ref => mediator ! DistributedPubSubMediator.Subscribe(topic, ref); ref }

  val wrapWithPublish =
    Flow[In].map(DistributedPubSubMediator.Publish(topic, _))

  val unsubscribe = DistributedPubSubMediator.Unsubscribe(topic, ref???)

  val toPubsub =
    Sink.actorRef[DistributedPubSubMediator.Publish](mediator, unsubscribe)

  Flow.fromSinkAndSource(wrapWithPublish to toPubsub, source)
}
```

The problem is in the definition of `unsubscribe`, I want to send a `DistributedPubSubMediator.Subscribe` by the end of the stream, which specifies a `ref` that should be the materialised value of `source` defined above.

I know that the Pubsub will automatically unsubscribe the Actor when it dies by the end of the stream. But I am curious how to solve the problem anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you will need to construct a Flow that is more tightly knit than `fromSinkAndSource`, you will need to use the GraphDSL:

```
val source = ... // as above
Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(source) { implicit b =>
  src =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._
    val concat = b.add(Concat[Any](2))
    val wrapWithPublish = b.add(Flow[In].map(DistributedPubSubMediator.Publish(topic, _)))
    val toPubSub = b.add(Sink.actorRef[Any](mediator, unsubscribe))

    wrapWithPublish ~> concat ~> toPubSub
    b.materializedValue.map(DistributedPubSubMediator.Unsubscribe(topic, _)) ~> concat

    FlowShape(wrapWithPublish.in, src.out)
})
```

This way you can inject the materialized value of one of the parts into the level of stream elements, making it accessible for being sent to the pubsub mediator.